# Python list comprehensions with regular expressions on a text

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a text file which includes integers in the text. There are one or more integers in a line or none. I want to find these integers with regular expressions and compute the sum.

I have managed to write the code:

```
import re
doc = raw_input("File Name:")
text = open(doc)
lst = list()
total = 0

for line in text:
    nums = re.findall("[0-9]+", line)
    if len(nums) == 0:
        continue
    for num in nums:
        num = int(num)
        total += num
print total
```

But i also want to know the list comprehension version, can someone help?

Comment: BTW... you don't need `if len(nums) == 0`. If there are none, the `for` loop will do nothing any way.

Comment: @zvone thanks for info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to calculate the sum of the numbers after you find them It's better to use a generator expression with `re.finditer()` within `sum()`. Also if the size of file in not very huge you better to read it at once, rather than one line at a time.

```
import re
doc = raw_input("File Name:")
with open(doc) as f:
    text = f.read()

total = sum(int(g.group(0)) for g in re.finditer(r'\d+', text))
```

Comment: thanks, and there is also a two-line version can u help on that :`import re
print sum( [ __________('[0-9]+',_________.read()) ] )`

Comment: @user6561340 There is no need to write it in two line. But if you want to practice, just try it and see the result.

Comment: Thanks for help :)